# Generate radio button whit twig according bootstrap style

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm trying to generate the radio butting according the bootstrap style but is is not yet working. In Symfony I use the following code to the form option:

```
       ->add('business', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array('Business' => true, 'Private' => false),
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'choices_as_values' => true,
        ))
```

With the following twig code:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                {{ form_widget(form.accountreg.business) }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

It generates the following html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
      <div id="cuslocation_accountreg_business">
         <input type="radio" id="cuslocation_accountreg_business_0" name="cuslocation[accountreg][business]" required="required" value="0" />
         <label for="cuslocation_accountreg_business_0" class="required">Business</label>
         <input type="radio" id="cuslocation_accountreg_business_1" name="cuslocation[accountreg][business]" required="required" value="1" />
         <label for="cuslocation_accountreg_business_1" class="required">Private</label>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to generate the following html code so it gets the bootstrap looks:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
      <div id="cuslocation_accountreg_business">
         <label class="required radio-inline" for="cuslocation_accountreg_business_0">
            <input type="radio" id="cuslocation_accountreg_business_0" name="cuslocation[accountreg][business]" required="required" value="0" />Business
         </label>
         <label class="required radio-inline" for="cuslocation_accountreg_business_1">
            <input type="radio" id="cuslocation_accountreg_business_1" name="cuslocation[accountreg][business]" required="required" value="1" />Private
          </label>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What is the best way to generate this in twig?

Answer (score 1):

there is a way to theme the forms in a way it has to be for Bootstrap 3 standard definition. Since Symfony 2.6 you are able to activate the built-in boostrap 3 theme in your config.yml

Please have a look: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme

But if you are using Symfony >2.8 the described way is deprecated. So please consider the "new" configuration way you'll find there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#twig

Hope this will help you,

Kind regards!

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I did not know this exists. I have tried it but do not like all the re-defined bootstrap classes like col-sm-3, in my case it needs to be wider.

Comment: You are even able to override the bootstrap theme file. There are different ways that are listed and documented under the following link. I already used "method 2: inside a separate template" which is very useful for specific customizations: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig

Answer (score 0):

You can style form in twig instead:

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.age) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.name, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}
</div>
```

And so on. [Link to docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Edit: [More suitable for the question](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form)

Comment: I know that just ads a class to the input field. But I want to nestle the input field in the label field. The form_label only gives the main name of the field not all the child names of the options

Comment: Then you can override choice widget with your logic, like here: [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig#L95) and then use like this: [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form)